# Electron production build - ProtocolDeprecateCallback: The callback argument of protocol module APIs is no longer needed

Tags: node.js, vue.js, electron

I have a working dev app in electron that will refuse to run in production due to this strange error

```
(node:10285) ProtocolDeprecateCallback: The callback argument of protocol module APIs is no longer needed.
writeOut @ internal/process/warning.js:32
```

I've build the app in past with success and was working, but now I have this problem.
This is the `background.js` file of the electron app I think that the error can be cause from something inside this file

```
'use strict'

import { app, protocol, BrowserWindow } from 'electron';
import { createProtocol } from 'vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder/lib';
import installExtension, { VUEJS_DEVTOOLS } from 'electron-devtools-installer';
import path from 'path';
import './ipc-services';
const isDevelopment = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';

// Scheme must be registered before the app is ready
protocol.registerSchemesAsPrivileged([
  { scheme: 'app', privileges: { secure: true, standard: true } }
]);

async function createWindow() {
  // Create the browser window.
  const win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      // Use pluginOptions.nodeIntegration, leave this alone
      // See nklayman.github.io/vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder/guide/security.html#node-integration for more info
//If I enable context isolation window.ipcRenderer will stop working also with preload.js script loaded
      //contextIsolation: true,
      nodeIntegration: process.env.ELECTRON_NODE_INTEGRATION,
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js'),
      icon: path.join(__static, 'icon.png')
    }
  });

  if (process.env.WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_URL) {
    // Load the url of the dev server if in development mode
    win.loadURL(process.env.WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_URL)
    if (!process.env.IS_TEST) win.webContents.openDevTools();
  } else {
    createProtocol('app');
    // Load the index.html when not in development
    win.loadURL(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'));
  }
}



// Quit when all windows are closed.
app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  // On macOS it is common for applications and their menu bar
  // to stay active until the user quits explicitly with Cmd + Q
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit();
  }
})

app.on('activate', () => {
  // On macOS it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
  // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
  if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) createWindow();
})

// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
// Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
app.on('ready', async () => {
  if (isDevelopment && !process.env.IS_TEST) {
    // Install Vue Devtools
    try {
      await installExtension(VUEJS_DEVTOOLS);
    } catch (e) {
      console.error('Vue Devtools failed to install:', e.toString());
    }
  }
  createWindow();
});

// Exit cleanly on request from parent process in development mode.
if (isDevelopment) {
  if (process.platform === 'win32') {
    process.on('message', (data) => {
      if (data === 'graceful-exit') {
        app.quit();
      }
    })
  } else {
    process.on('SIGTERM', () => {
      app.quit();
    });
  }
}
```

Is there a fix that I can apply?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of research and debug I've discovered two problems in my code. The first one is that `process.env.IS_TEST` is not defined, I've removed that line from my code. No problem occur in `electron:serve` mode. The main problem with the blank screen in production instead, was because `win.loadURL(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'))` was trying to load the files ufing the `file:` protocol instead of the custom one registered from the app.
I've reverted back to the original code and used the `win.loadURL('app://./index.html')`
After this little modification the app seems working fine also in production.